# Problemas com Decode e Arduino

Tags: python, c, arduino, serial

Olá, Pessoas

Tenho o seguinte código no Arduino

```
if((digitalRead(4) != 1)||(digitalRead(5) != 1))
  {
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(millis());
      Serial.print("\n");
  }
```

E com ele, eu leio no Python com o seguinte código:

```
def leituraSerial():
    tempo_leitura = time.time() + (TIMER + 1.6) # Contador de TIMER segundos
    k = 0

    while(time.time() <= tempo_leitura):  

        print("\n Leitura Iniciada!")

        aux = entrada.readline()
        str(aux)
        print(aux.decode('ascii'))
```

Tentei diversos encodings de cp1252, windows-1250, utf-8, latin_1 e etc.. alguns retornam \x00 com o valor que eu queria, outros dão erro, o jeito que está o código acima, ele roda, porém se eu adicionar, por exemplo:

```
ts, tp = aux.split(",")
```

Já me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Se usar utf-8:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 6: invalid start byte
```

Então, o que diabos está acontecendo???

Comment: O `str(aux)` não está fazendo nada; `str()` retorna o valor de uma string, e não a modifica. O que acontece se você faz `print(str(aux))` sem o `decode`?

Comment: Se me lembro bem, vem um byte-object, b'\t0,4998\n', por exemplo.

Answer (score 3):

O problema não está do lado do Python  -

Suas funçoes em C não devem estar retornando strings, e sim, números - o que significa que o número que está indo para a string comunicada é lixo (o número inteiro retornado pelas suas funções é interpretado como um endereço de memória - o print vai lá e lê o conteúdo daquele endereço até achar um valor de 0x00  e coloca o que tiver encontrado na string.

Se em vez de Arduino, na outra ponta, você tivesse executando seu programa sob um sistema operacional com gerenciamento de acesso a memória por processo, seu programa pararia com um segmentation fault. Mas numa máquina 8 bits, qualquer programa em C tem poderes equivalentes aos do Kernel do sistema.

PAra resolver isso, se quiser mandar seus dados como texto, use a função `itoa` no lado do C- deve ficar algo como:

```
<include stdlib.h>
...
   char tmp[20];
...
if((digitalRead(4) != 1)||(digitalRead(5) != 1))
  {

      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(itoa(analogRead(A0), tmp, 10));
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(itoa(millis(), tmp, 10));
      Serial.print("\n");
  }
```

Então essa é sua resposta.

Para completar a informação sobre a codificação: você não tem que se preocupar com a codificação a não ser que esteja usando caractéres acentuados no seu programa no Arduino. Se estiver - vamos supor que você estivesse mandando uma tabela completa e a primeira linha do cabeçalho fosse "leitura analógica, milisegundos\n"  - nesse caso seria só usar a mesma codificação usada no arquivo em C em que você escreveu essa string, antes de compilar. A linguagem C não "sabe" de texto, só "bytes" -  então se o seu arquivo em C original estivesse em utf-8, o "ó" de analógico estaria no programa objeto, dentro do arduíno como a sequência `"\xc3\xb3" - que ao ser recebida no Python, e tratada com ".decode('utf-8')", viraria de volta a letra "ó".

Comment: Obrigado pela a luz, mas o problema ainda persiste.

Comment: você tem que explorar os dados que está efetivamente recebendo do lado do Python - simplesmente imprima a sequência de bytes na tela, e vai ver o que chega, sem fazer nenhum decode. Também pode usar o codec "latin1": ele nunca dá erro de "decode", já que tem caractéres definidos para todos os valores possívels de 0 a 255 (não quer dizer que o texto vá ser o correto). 
O método `hex()` do objeto bytes, em vez do "decode" vai te dar uma string com dois dígitos hexa pra cada byte também - fácil de visualizar os dados.

Comment: Então, usando o latin-1, o código começou a dar certo, mas na primeira leitura sempre retorna um caractere aleatório não esperado, como ü       0,1 , por exemplo, o esperado seria apenas o 0,1, o que de fato acontece com as leituras restantes, isso atrapalha na conversão que faço pra float

Comment: voce mudou o código em C no dispositivo como está na questão? um caractére como "ü" inesperado é um forte indicativo de que voce está esperando dados como texto no computador, mas não está enviando os dados como texto de lá.

Comment: Sim, usei o itoa pra garantir strings, isso acontece apenas a primeira linha, então apenas ignorei a primeira linha, mas é uma gambiarra...